# Built App in Xcode 10, now stuck on LaunchScreen after upgrading to Xcode 11 & Simulator iOS 13

Tags: ios13, simulator, launch, xcode11

I've seen some questions on here with problems after updating to Xcode 11, but haven't seen a solution that really helps me. I've been building my first app for a few months now. I updated to Xcode 11 to test it on my physical iPhone 11 Pro. Now, whenever I build and run on a simulator running iOS 13.0 or higher, I get no errors, but the app never makes it past the LaunchScreen. In the debug area, it says that the first View Controller in my Main.Storyboard has loaded (prints out all the print statements I have in the VC code), but the launch screen stays on the simulator. Interestingly, if I change the storyboard entry point to a Dummy View Controller with a green background and a label, that VC will display on the simulator.

I know that I'll need to update my app using SwiftUI and SceneDelegate etc soon, but I would like to release the app as is (while I learn SwiftUI and the new Xcode capabilities) if it's possible to make it compatible with iOS 13 without doing a lot of work for the time being. Is this possible or not?

Below is the output from the debug area and a screenshot of my project navigator and my info.plist.

Thanks in advance for any and all feedback!

```
capsule home loaded
812.0 frame height
Optional(file:///Users/christophermurray/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A61D294D-A5DC-4CF2-83C4-68AECCF80A65/data/Containers/Data/Application/AC4D353D-B367-4D58-8B26-9E0C5DEA5E41/Documents/default.realm)
26CF4CCF-5D21-4809-B1D1-7CA833F6181A
Capsule {
    itemArray = List<string> <0x6000004b4e10> (

    );
    buryDate = (null);
    digUpDate = (null);
    itemID = 2CDF3EB3-5573-4401-AF21-47AAAF89B6BB;
} added to realm
1 # of Capsules
LazyFilterSequence<List<StoredItem>>(_base: List<StoredItem> <0x600003820600> (

), _predicate: (Function))
0
true
check update status ran
(0.0, -362.0, 375.0, 0.0)
(0.0, -362.0, 375.0, 0.0)
2019-12-24 17:30:01.476817+1100 TimeCapsule[81727:3933767] Version 4.3.0 of Realm is now available: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/v4.3.0/CHANGELOG.md
```

[Project Navigator and info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hruI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If empty view controller works correctly then issue with your code or with third-party libraries. Per your log we can see you are using old Realm library, there are fixes for Xcode 11/iOS 13 in new one and it is strongly recommended to upgrade. Other dependencies may also have useful fixes for new iOS release.

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't Realm which was causing the hangup but one of my other pods. Works perfectly now on iOS 13

Comment: You also need to have a launch storyboard as opposed to a launchimage in ios 13